# Express routes issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to start my Node.js server, I have 2 files: my app.js

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  morgan = require('morgan'),
  consign = require('consign'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  passportConfig = require('./passport')(passport),
  jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
  config = require('./index.js');

  app.use(express.static('.'));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(passport.initialize());



 app.set('playersecret', config.secret);
 consign({ cwd: 'services' })
.include('Player/app/setup/')
.then('Player/app/api/')
.then('Player/app/routes/')
.into(app);
module.exports = app;
```

and /app/routes/auth.js

```
const models = require('@Player/app/setup');

module.exports = (app) => {
const api = app.PlayerAPI.app.api.auth;
app.route('/',).get((req,res) => res.send('Player API'));
app.post('/api/auth/',api.login(models.User));
}
```

and as I understood my routes are not imported to `app.js`, because if I write code right in `app.js`, it works fine.

How do I import it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your `auth.js` routes defined is that it accepts the `app` instance, so you would need to do the following in your `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const authRoutes = require('./app/routes/auth.js')

const app = express()

// ... 

authRoutes(app)
```

Alternatively you can just inline the require although I find that messy (personal opinion):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// ...

require('./app/routes/auth.js')(app)
```

A better approach would be to export a [`router`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router) object:

`/app/routes/auth.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const models = require('@Player/app/setup')
const api = require('./path/to/PlayerAPI.js')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', ...)
router.post('/', api.login(models.User))

module.exports = router
```

`app.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const authRoutes = require('./app/routes/auth.js')
const app = express()

// ...

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a `JS` file, you have to include the file name at the beginning of your `app.js` as shown below:

```
var express = require('express')
var auth = require(./app/routes/auth.js)
```

You can learn more about importing in javascript file in the `express.js` official document file.